# apache-cassandra-4.0.7 Dockerfile Unavailable exception

Tags: docker, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Trying to create docker image from apache-cassandra-4.0.7-bin.tar.gz but getting following error after configring keyspace

`$ docker exec -it pidcss /bin/bash`

`$ ./cqlsh localhost -u cassandra -p cassandra`

`Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9042`

`[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.7 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]`

`Use HELP for help.`

```
cassandra@cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE pid
   ...   WITH REPLICATION = { 
   ...    'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 
   ...    'replication_factor' : 0 
   ...   };
cassandra@cqlsh> use pid
   ... ;
cassandra@cqlsh:pid> CREATE TABLE if not exists vis (parentid text, type text,  PRIMARY 
KEY (parentid));

cassandra@cqlsh:pid> describe tables;

$ ./cqlsh localhost -u cassandra -p cassandra
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9042
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.7 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
cassandra@cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE pid WITH REPLICATION = { 
'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 
'replication_factor' : 0 
 };
cassandra@cqlsh> use pid
   ... ;
cassandra@cqlsh:pid> CREATE TABLE if not exists vis (parentid text, type text,  PRIMARY KEY (parentid));
cassandra@cqlsh:pid> describe tables;
vismenu
```

`cassandra@cqlsh:pid> select * from vis ; NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {<Host: 127.0.0.1:9042 datacenter1>: Unavailable('Error from server: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve consistency level ONE" info={\'consistency\': \'ONE\', \'required_replicas\': 1, \'alive_replicas\': 0}')}) cassandra@cqlsh:pid>`

Any idea on what could help resolve this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear if the docker image got pulled successfully & set up correct. At a high level the steps would look like,

- `docker pull cassandra:4.0.11` or use the latest tag `docker pull cassandra:latest` from https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/tags?page=1
- `docker network create cassandra`
- `docker run --rm -d --name cassandra --hostname cassandra --network cassandra cassandra` and let it start up fully
- `docker run --rm -it --network cassandra nuvo/docker-cqlsh cqlsh cassandra 9042 --cqlversion='3.4.5'` to start an interactive CQLSHell

(Optional clean-up activities)

```
docker kill cassandra
docker network rm cassandra
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: with steps above :
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE pid WITH REPLICATION = { class' : 'SimpleStrategy',replication_factor' : 0 };
cqlsh:pid> CREATE TABLE cycling_race_winners (race_name text, race_position int,
PRIMARY KEY (race_name, race_position)) ;
cqlsh:pid> select * from cycling_race_winners ;
NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {<Host: 172.18.0.2 datacenter1>: Unavailable('Error from server: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve consistency level ONE" info={\'required_replicas\': 1, \'alive_replicas\': 0, \'consistency\': \'ONE\'}',)})

Comment: Thanks Madhavan, I was able to resolve the issue with above steps. But i have new issue now. as i specifiy --hostname cassandra in run, i am unable to access the cassandra from machine external to docker host. i am able to access it with cqlsh using name on same host only. So if you can help with how to bind ubuntu host name to cassandra docker -hostname it would be great.

Comment: I was able to resolve the same with following docker run : docker run -p 0.0.0.0:9042:9042 --rm --name cassandra --network cassandra cassandra:4.0.6

Comment: GTK that your issue is now resolved! Cheers.